# Best Practice For Deploying and Running Periodic Spark Job

Tags: apache-spark, batch-processing

I have a number of spark batch jobs each of which need to be run every x hours. I'm sure this must be a common problem but there seems to be relatively little on the internet as to what the best practice is here for setting this up.  My current setup is as follows:

1. Build system (sbt) builds a tar.gz containing a fat jar + a script that will invoke spark-submit.
2. Once tests have passed, CI system (Jenkins) copies the tar.gz to hdfs.
3. I set up a [chronos](https://mesos.github.io/chronos/) job to unpack the tar.gz to the local filesystem and run the script that submits to spark.

This setup works reasonably well, but there are some aspects of step 3) that I'm not fond of.  Specifically:

- I need a separate script (executed by chronos) that copies from hdfs, unpacks and runs the spark-submit task.  As far as I can tell chrons can't run scripts from hdfs so I have to have a copy of this script on every mesos worker which makes deployment more complex that it would be if everything just lived on hdfs.
- I have a feeling that I have too many moving parts.  For example I was wondering if I could create an executable jar that could submit itself (args would be the spark master and the main class) in which case I would do away with at least one of the wrapper scripts.  Unfortunately I haven't found a good way of doing this

As this is a problem that everyone faces I was wondering if anyone could give a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

To download and extract archive you can use Mesos [fetcher](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/fetcher/) by specifying it in Chronos job config by setting *uris* field.
To do the same procedure on executors side you can set s*park.executor.uri* parameter in default Spark conf